# how to convert attribute/variable using node js

Tags: node.js, chatfuel

I created a bot from chat fuel. and it is asking about gender the bot make you choose if male or female..both is set to one attribute `gender` but what I wanted to do is to change the value of each selected like if I select male the value would be 1 and if female 0 ..

[image: this is what it looks like...]

what happen is when it saves to my db `gender = male` or `gender = female` what I wanted to achieve is when I select male the value that will be saved is 1 and if female 0 so it would look like on my db `gender = 1` if `male` and `gender = 0` if `female`

```
router.post('/chatbot_patient', (req, res) => {
    var ref = database.ref('patients');
    var body = _.pick(_.assign(patient, req.body), _.keys(patient));


    body['client_fk'] = req.body['chatfuel user id'];

    req.body['1'] = req.body['male'];
    req.body['0'] = req.body['female'];
    body['gender'] = req.body['gender1'];
    body['createdAt'] = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    ref.push(body);

    res.json({
                 "messages": [
                   {"text": "You are now registered as iWatcher."}
                 ]
                });
});
```

this is what my node script looks.  I tried converting it but it doesn't work.. is there a way to do it on node?

Comment: I thing you could explain better in which value you are sending the gender and with what format. And then, what do you want to do with it. Right now I don't anderstand what you are looking for.

Comment: Need Some clarification about question.

Comment: i updated my question... that is what i wanted to achieve.. instead of saving male | female will saved 1 | 0 as gender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to take the value and set it in another variable:

```
var gender = req.body['gender'] === 'male' ? 1: 0;
```

Comment: this is great... can i ask where did you find this?

Comment: It is a ternary operator. It is very similar to if / else. Google it, is very common and useful